# iphone: memory leak while reading data in loop from datatbase

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

Can anybody help me out why this piece of code is leaking and how can we handle it?

```
const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM VIOLATIONS_TBL";

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSString *recSTR=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
        [self.pickerList addObject:recSTR];
        [recSTR release];
        recSTR=nil;             

    }
}
```

recSTR is leaking in this case and I have tried all the below mentioned solutions but none worked
Thanx in advance

Comment: pickerList is an array of arrays and the inner array contains one string. Thus tempRowArray has a retain count of 1, otherwise pickerList would have pointers to invalid references. Releasing or clearing pickerList should relase all tempRowArrays. Where is the leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your loop is running for a huge number of times then use autorelease pool

> loop { 
>  
>       NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
>
> ```
> ...code goes here...
>
> [innerPool release];
> ```
>
> }

It might help you prevent memory leak

Comment: How does a autorelease pool prevent leaks? Its only useful to relinquish ownership of objects that should not be deallocated within the currents pool scope. Its not a magic garbage collector.

Comment: Every time autorelease is sent to an object, it is added to the outer-most autorelease pool. When the pool is drained, it simply sends release to all the objects in the pool.

Comment: yupp its not fixing the issue leak is still there

Comment: One thing can also be done. Make an instance of NSString where it is leaking and then you can release that string or make it auto release. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution leak is here

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]
```

handle this and we are done

Comment: Please share your complete solution..how you handled this?That will helpful for community

Comment: Did you change your original question? Kind of confusing as I tried to find the leak in the code you posted in your question.

Comment: @PHP: HE have used `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]
` line instead of `NSString *recSTR=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];` one